# Error while playing scene: "There are no scenes in that module"

Tags: manim

I installed manim with all relevant dependencies and while trying to test it by doing some of the example scenes, the following error occurred

```
[03/05/21 23:02:26] ERROR                                                                                             module_ops.py:71
                                There are no scenes inside that module
```

I installed manim by copying the repo with git. Then I made another file with code copied from this tutorial https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/getting-started-animating-with-manim-and-python-3-7/ to see if the problem was on the example_scenes.py file, but i got the same result with an example from that page. I'm running Debian 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONE NOTE: The article you used is great, but it's a bit outdated now. For example, to import the manim module, it is no longer `from big_ol_pile_of_manim_imports import *` but it's `from manim import *`.

Can you please tell us your manim version (i.e. community vs. Grant's version), all the dependencies you installed, and what command you use in terminal to call manim?

There are tutorials for the manim community edition linked [here](https://docs.manim.community/en/v0.4.0/tutorials/quickstart.html) (if you downloaded the community edition). Let me know if you have any questions, hope this helps!

Comment: I was using Grant's version. The dependencies I installed were the usual latex, ffmpeg and whatever is on the requirements.txt that's on the folder when you copy from Grant's GitHub. I tried installing the community version and after installing missing dependencies I reached the same problem as before, "no scenes on the module". For Grant's version I call it with manimgl (which now says: AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'config') and manim for the community's.
Thanks for answering!

Comment: Update: The error I had when using the Community version was by using some of the examples from Grant's version. I tried using code from the Quickstart community guide you posted and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Theorem of Beethoven made a new video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Upztg_Bs-zs&t=1s, for anyone who is having difficulty installing!